# how to downgrade chromedriver version for python3 on mac?

Tags: python, macos, selenium-chromedriver, version, downgrade

I used chromedriver with python3.7 to parse html on macOS 10.9, pip3 install chromedriver version 2.41, and chrome is version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit), now I got error message as below, what can I do next?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 67.0.3396.0
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578706 (5f725d1b4f0a4acbf5259df887244095596231db),platform=Mac OS X 1231384169.10.64 x86_64)
```

Comment: Download whichever version you want and put the exe in your path ==> https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!